# QML Cannot assign to non-existent property

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5

I'm trying to create a custom QML object. I started simple, by making a qml file called **rect.qml**:

```
import QtQuick 2.2
Rectangle 
{ }
```

*In the same directory*, I wanted to use my rect object in a seperate qml file, called **window.qml**:

```
import QtQuick 2.2
Item {
  id: mainWindow
  rect
  { }
}
```

Very high caliber stuff, I know. Anyway, when I try to run my application, I get the following error:

**qrc:/qml/window.qml:3:13: Cannot assign to non-existent property "rect"**

So I checked my QRC file, and it goes as such:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/qml">
        <file>window.qml</file>
        <file>rect.qml</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

According to the documentation (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-documents-definetypes.html) this application isn't very useful as it's so bare bones, (simplified for my question,) but there shouldn't be an error.

Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried renaming it to Rect.qml and consequently in window.qml?

Comment: You guys nailed it! Thank you for your time and feedback!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must rename the file to `Rect.qml` and call it `Rect{}`

Answer (score 4):

QML imposes some limitations on how you can name things, QML documents or exposed C++ enums keys must begin with capital letters, and properties or ids must **not** begin with a capital letter. I don't recall this being documented in one single, convenient article as it should. Most are documented, but it is spread all over the place.

Comment: Yes, the name was the problem. I agree, it's frustrating to be subject not-explicitly outlined limitations that is specific to this language. Thank you for your time!